# How to get record for highest value based on type and 2 columns

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a table here called my_table

```
| userid | gender | year | money |
| ------ | ------ | ---- | ----- |
| 1      | B      | 12   | 50    |
| 1      | B      | 24   | 150   |
| 1      | B      | 36   | 5     |
| 1      | G      | 0    | 0     |
| 1      | G      | 12   | 120   |
| 1      | G      | 48   | 120   |
| 2      | B      | 12   | 23    |
| 2      | B      | 24   | 56    |
| 2      | G      | 36   | 23    |
| 3      | G      | 0    | 234   |
| 3      | G      | 12   | 34    |
| 4      | G      | 0    |  0    |
```

I want to return the row for the highest money available based on the gender.
So for example, the return table for gender B will be like

```
| userid | gender | year | money |
| ------ | ------ | ---- | ----- |
| 1      | B      | 24   | 150   |
| 2      | B      | 24   | 56    |
```

And the return table for gender G will be like

```
| userid | gender | year | money |
| ------ | ------ | ---- | ----- |
| 1      | G      | 12   | 120   |
| 1      | G      | 48   | 120   |
| 2      | G      | 36   | 23    |
| 3      | G      | 0    | 234   |
| 4      | G      | 0    | 0     |
```

But since the table for gender G has duplicated value of money, I want it to return the row with the highest year.
Expected table for gender G is

```
| userid | gender | year | money |
| ------ | ------ | ---- | ----- |
| 1      | G      | 48   | 120   |
| 2      | G      | 36   | 23    |
| 3      | G      | 0    | 234   |
| 4      | G      | 0    | 0     |
```

What I have tried : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5433cbc/2
I am able to get the table for gender B but not gender G.

What I am trying to achieve is to generate a table joining both of the gender table above into one. Example,

```
| userid | year_b | max_money_for_b | year_g | max_money_for_g |
| ------ | ------ | --------------- | ------ | --------------- |
| 1      | 24     | 150             | 48     | 120             |
| 2      | 24     | 56              | 36     | 23              |
| 3      | null   | null            | 0      | 234             |
| 4      | null   | null            | 0      | 0               |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a correlated subquery is the simplest approach in MySQL:

```
select t.*
from my_table t
where t.gender = 'G' and
      (t.year, t.money) = (select t2.year, t2.money
                           from my_table t2
                           where t2.userid = t.userid and
                                 t2.gender = t.gender
                           order by t2.money desc, t2.year desc
                           limit 1
                          );
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution is way simpler and easier to understand

Answer (score 1):

As below, I think you would get the right results.

```
select
    m.userid,
    m.gender,
    tmp1.m_money as money,
    tmp2.m_year as year
from
    my_table m
join
(
select
    gender,
    userid,
    max(money) as m_money
from
    my_table
group by
    gender,
    userid
) tmp1 on m.gender = tmp1.gender and m.userid=tmp1.userid and m.money=tmp1.m_money
join
(
select
    gender,
    userid,
    money,
    max(year) as m_year
from
    my_table
group by
    gender,
    userid,
    money
) tmp2 on m.gender = tmp2.gender and m.userid=tmp2.userid and m.money=tmp2.money and m.year=tmp2.m_year
where m.gender='G'
order by m.gender,m.userid
```

If you use the PostgreSQL or MySQL which version is greater than 8.0, things will be simplier, you can just use the window function to implement your requirement.As below:

```
select * from 
(
select
    user_id,
    gender,
    money,
    year,
    row_number() over(partition by userid,gender order by money desc,year desc) as sort
from
    my_table
) tmp where sort = 1
```

Comment: Where can i specify to have only the gender G or B? Your query returns both gender and also duplicated values. You can check here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5433cbc/9
Also I cant use the row_number() coz my db is not updated.

Comment: I have fixed the join error, now please see in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5433cbc/12 , I think it has solved your problem, there is no duplicated values in result.

Comment: I updated my question. Hope you guys can understand better

Comment: so you just want show G's value and B's value in just one row for each userId?

Comment: Yes correct. I havent implemented your query yet. Will try it once i get back home. Since your query is able to pull out correct values for the G table then i think should be no problem to left join them

Comment: Right, then join B's value and G's value by userid , you will get the final result.

Comment: Please click the accept button for me, thanks.  ;-) .

Answer (score 0):

remove the condition `gender = 'G'` from your where condition

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5433cbc/5)**

```
select t.* from my_table t where
not exists (
    select 1 from my_table where userid = t.userid and money > t.money
        or (money = t.money and year > t.year)
    )
```

Comment: I need the condition checking because i am planning to join both of the gender B and G table into another table and display 2 column as B_max_money, G_max_money, B_year, etc